# Resize a Widget Vertically with gestures Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, resize, vertical-alignment, drag

I need to resize a widget from top and bottom on drag in Flutter. Does someone know how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Resize Widget](https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_widget) package for your requirements

Comment: I believe this package only helps to move the widget, but I need the user to resize it by dragging it up and down

Comment: You can use resizable_widget package also

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how to use it with a table, if you have an experience with a dynamic table(not datatable or gridview) do you maybe know if the resizeable_widget package can help me make a resizeable table with gestures?